# How to reference generic Alamofire DataResponse value

Tags: swift, alamofire

I would like to write a method that can accept any Alamofire DataResponse value. For example, I might pass in `DataResponse<Any>` or `DataResponse<String>`. I cannot find a way to get this to work however. For example if I try just using "DataResonse" like this

```
static func isTimeout(response: DataResponse) -> Bool {
    if let error = response.result.error {
        if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I get a compile error:

```
Reference to generic type 'DataResponse' requires arguments in <...>
Insert <Any>.
```

However if I change the parameter type to be `DataResponse<Any>`, it will not work for when I have `DataResponse<String>`. The compile error I get when I try to pass `DataResponse<String>` into the function is:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<String>' to expected argument type 'DataResponse<Any>'
```

I also tried `DataResponse<AnyObject>` and got the same error as above
and `DataResponse<Value>` and got this error:

```
Use of undeclared type 'Value'
```

Any ideas on how to do this so I don't have to duplicate functions just for the slightly different parameter type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your forget to infer the generic type. Try this:

```
static func isTimeout<T>(response: DataResponse<T>) -> Bool {
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the syntax to put <T> after the function name. So in my above example when I tried DataResponse<Value>, it looks like it would have worked if I did isTimeout<Value>? Thanks! It is working now.

Comment: Yes it's should work, it's just a name convention. things in <> are called Type parameters, sometimes they are descriptive such as Key and Value in Dictionary<Key, Value>, sometimes not if there isn't a meaningful relationship,  it’s traditional to name them using single letters such as T, U, and V